# Only compiles as an array of pointers, not array of arrays

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I define two arrays, each of which have 2 elements (for theoretical purposes):

```
char const *arr1[] = { "i", "j" };
char const *arr2[] = { "m", "n" };
```

Is there a way to define a multidimensional array that contains these two arrays as elements?  I was thinking of something like the following, but my compiler displays warnings about incompatible types:

```
char const *combine[][2] = { arr1, arr2 };
```

The only way it would compile was to make the compiler treat the arrays as pointers:

```
char const *const *combine[] = { arr1, arr2 };
```

Is that really the only way to do it or can I preserve the type somehow (in C++, the runtime type information would know it is an array) and treat `combine` as a multidimensional array?  I realise it works because an array name is a const pointer, but I'm just wondering if there is a way to do what I'm asking in standard C/C++ rather than relying on compiler extensions.  Perhaps I've gotten a bit too used to Python's lists where I could just throw anything in them...

Comment: Interesting problem. I don't know the solution, but I'll be watching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. First, this

```
char const *combine[][2] = { arr1, arr2 };
```

cannot work, because `arr1` and `arr2` cannot be used to initialize an array. But this:

```
char const *arr1[] = { "i", "j" };
char const *arr2[] = { "m", "n" };

char const *(*combine[])[2] = { &arr1, &arr2 };
```

works as well as this

```
char const *arr1[] = { "i", "j" };
char const *arr2[] = { "m", "n" };

char const *combine[][2] = { {"i", "j"}, {"m", "n"} };
```

Comment: Interesting solution...  An array of pointers to arrays each of length 2 containing values of type `char const *` (or `const char *` if you prefer; they're the same thing).  The extra level of indirection is a bit of a nuisance when I want to use the arrays contained in `combine`, but I like the idea because it does exactly what I asked!  Not only that, you showed how to do it generically with any arrays of the same length.  Thanks a bunch!  ^_^

Comment: In const char *arr1[], arr1 is an array of pointers to const char, in char *const arr1[], arr1 is an array of const pointers to char, but char const *arr1[]... Is it a compiler extension?

Comment: Notice that you have to access the arrays as `combine[i][0][j]` or `(*combine[i])[j]` in the first case. In the second case it's just `combine[i][j]`. Another interesting fact is that in C you don't even need to specify the `2`, because `T[]` is *compatible* with `T[N]`. You can just say `char const *(*combine[])[] = { &arr1, &arr2 };`. However you can then only use the `(*combine[i])[j]` form of accessing (because `sizeof *combine[i]` is unknown). That's a C speciality only, though. In C++ you need to specify the size.